# Negative Binomial Distribution questions

Tags: negative-binomial

In 2016, Red Rose tea randomly began placing one of ten English porcelain miniature figurines in a l00 bag box of the tea, selecting from ten figurines in the American Heritage Series.
(a) On the average, how many boxes of tea must be purchased by a customer to obtain a complete collection consisting of the ten different figurines?
(b) If the customer uses one tea bag per day, how long can a customer expect to take? on the average, to obtain a complete collection?

For this question, I don't even know where to start. Can someone please give me hint?

Comment: This is a re-phrasing of the classical [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)